# Displaying a user's individual and group views simultaneously in Django

Tags: django, permissions, view, usergroups

I'm having trouble displaying a user's individual and group entries simultaneously.

My group model is written as such:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='entry_users')
```

My entry model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ###
    authorized_groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', null=True, blank=True, related_name='entry_groups')
    objects = EntryManager()
```

Before the `Entry` model, I wrote an entry manager with a user filter.

If I want to display a user's individual entries, I use the following:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
     def for_user(self, user):
        return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(creator=user)
```

If I want to display a user's group entries, I use the following:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
     def for_user(self, user):
        return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(authorized_groups=user)
```

I want to combine the two versions of the `EntryManager` model into one. Right now, I can use either or, but not both. Any tips?

If it makes any difference, in `views.py`, I've got line of code that grabs all the objects for which a user has access:

```
entries = Entry.objects.for_user(request.user)
```

Perhaps I should keep both Entry Managers and write two different views - one for individual objects and another for group objects. That wouldn't be very DRY though.

Answer (score 0):

I kept the first `EntryManager`:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(creator=user)
```

And wrote a `GroupManager`:

```
GroupManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(EntryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(authorized_groups=user)
```

Then I placed both under my `Entry` model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ###
    objects = EntryManager()
    grpobjects = GroupManager()
```

In `views.py` I have this:

```
entries = Entry.objects.for_user(request.user) | Entry.grpobjects.for_user(request.user)
```

Seems to do the trick. If there's a better way though, please let me know.

Comment: Django makes the first manager listed the "default" manager, and it should *never* be filtered. You'll run into all kinds of problems with that, and you'll be left with no way to actually see all entries at once. Do `objects = models.Manager()` and then add your other two managers after that (assigning `EntryManager` to something other than `objects`, obviously).